# What is the proper way to return an error from gRPC ServerInterceptor

Tags: java, authentication, grpc, quarkus

I have a Quarkus application that uses gRPC.  I have implemented a ServerInterceptor to look for and validate auth tokens.

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class GrpcAuthInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {

    @Inject
    AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> serverCall, Metadata metadata, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> serverCallHandler) {
        String token = metadata.get(AuthenticationConstants.AUTH_HEADER_KEY);

        Context context = Context.current();

        if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(token)) {
            String fbToken = authenticationService.verifyIdToken(token);
            context = context.withValue(AuthenticationConstants.CONTEXT_FB_USER_KEY, fbToken);
        } else {
            serverCall.close(Status.UNAUTHENTICATED.withDescription("Auth Token Required"), metadata);
        }

        return Contexts.interceptCall(
                context,
                serverCall,
                metadata,
                serverCallHandler);
    }
}
```

This works and sends a message to the client like this:

```
gRPC Error (code: 16, codeName: UNAUTHENTICATED, message: Auth Token Required, details: [], rawResponse: null, trailers: {})
```

but it logs this error on the server because I didn't return from the method after sending the error:

```
2022-10-04 21:50:23,006 ERROR [io.qua.mut.run.MutinyInfrastructure] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0)
Mutiny had to drop the following exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: call is closed
```

Several posts suggest I can return an empty ServerCall.Listener like this:

```java
serverCall.close(Status.UNAUTHENTICATED.withDescription("Auth Token Required"), metadata);
return new ServerCall.Listener<ReqT>() {};
```

this works and gets rid of the server-side error message BUT it breaks the message returned to the client.  The client just gets this:

```java
gRPC Error (code: 2, codeName: UNKNOWN, message: null, details: [], rawResponse: null, trailers: {})
```

So my question is: how do I return a meaningful error message to the client and not log an exception server-side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could catch it all in a try block and send the message just in there; The issue you face is that you are first closing the call before returning it, so it tries to process an already closed pipe.

In the second scenario, as you send the "void" message right after the "close" message, the detailed message gets overriden.

Try something like:

```
@Override
public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> serverCall, Metadata metadata, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> serverCallHandler) 
{
    String token = metadata.get(AuthenticationConstants.AUTH_HEADER_KEY);
    Context context = Context.current();
    boolean mustClose=false;
    try
    {
       if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(token)) 
       {
           String fbToken = authenticationService.verifyIdToken(token);
           context = context.withValue(AuthenticationConstants.CONTEXT_FB_USER_KEY, fbToken);
           return Contexts.interceptCall(context,serverCall,metadata, serverCallHandler);
       } 
       else 
       {
           mustClose=true;
           return new ServerCall.Listener<ReqT>() {};
       }              
     } 
     finally 
     {
        if (mustClose)
             serverCall.close(Status.UNAUTHENTICATED.withDescription("Auth Token Required"), metadata);
     }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't fix it.  It still logs a server-side error because interceptCall isn't returning anything.   I don't need to return a message, but I may have a few different reasons for closing the connection and I'd like the client to know why.

Comment: hmmm, I see ... now I get your point

Comment: made an edit @TerrenceCurran, hope it helps

Comment: wow. I honestly wouldn't expect this to be any different than calling serverCall.close right before the return statement, but it seems to work! thanks!

Comment: the thing is that your last return overrides the previous one. So first, send the void message and afte that, your current detailed close message. Glad it helped, already upvoted the question (as made me think), so can't do it further ; )

Comment: @aran nice to see that you are still around

Comment: Great! **Suggestion**: I recommend using [try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) if it is supported by this API.